# Files and programs disappeared after Windows 10 update

Tags: windows, windows-10, updates, disc

I need help for my parents computer. They have Windows 10.

After an update installation all downloaded files were deleted, also some programs remained and some were deleted.

Since then, after every restart, new files and program are disappearing. Also, there is `windows.old` folder and it looks like the space is not freed.

Also I have this error in the update settings:

*ex. Update Settings Error*

[image: Update Settings Error - Screenshot]

I tried to follow this:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html

And got this subjection:

> Intel® Graphics - Windows® 10 DCH Drivers
>
> Installing this Intel generic graphics driver will overwrite any
> customized driver from your Computer Manufacturer (OEM).
>
> OEM drivers are handpicked, customized, and validated to resolve
> platform-specific issues, enable features and enhancements, and
> improve system stability. Intel’s generic graphics drivers are
> intended for testing, and we recommend using drivers from Lenovo.
> Report any issues found with this driver to Intel.

I don't know why would it effect the disc.
Any ideas what's happening?

Comment: Your files are likely contained within the Windows.old folder.  Can you confirm that’s the case?

Comment: As for the update error.  You should download the current device driver directly from Intel

Comment: See https://www.howtogeek.com/658194/windows-10s-new-update-is-deleting-peoples-files-again/